# GUI Reading from CSV

Tags: c#, csv

I have been working on converting a GUI script from another language to C# using VS2017. I have the whole thing working for the most part, but have come on a problem. The gui has a listview which I am populating either manually through entering data in various fields or as an import from a CSV. The manual entry works just fine. The CSV import works as well, however it is pulling the header line into the listview. Here is the code I am using for the button to kick off the import:

```
private void import(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog xls = new OpenFileDialog();
  xls.Multiselect = false;
  xls.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv";
  xls.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
  xls.ShowDialog();
  string ins;

  if (xls.FileName != null)
  {
    FileStream srcFS;
    srcFS = new FileStream(xls.FileName, FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader srcSR = new StreamReader(srcFS, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
    do
    {
        ins = srcSR.ReadLine();
        if (ins != null)
        {
            string[] parts = ins.Split(',');

            MyItems.Add(new MyItem
            {
                Name = parts[0],
                CPU = parts[1],
                RAM = parts[2],
                IP = parts[3],
                Subnet = parts[4],
                PortGroup = parts[5],
                Gateway = parts[6],
                DNS = parts[7],
                Description = parts[8],
                Template = parts[9],
                Host = parts[10],
                Site = parts[11],
                Folder = parts[12],
                Datastore = parts[13],
                Patch = parts[14],
                HDD1_Size = parts[15],
                HDD2_Size = parts[16],
                HDD3_Size = parts[17],
                HDD4_Size = parts[18],
                HDD5_Size = parts[19],
                HDD6_Size = parts[20],
                HDD7_Size = parts[21],
                HDD8_Size = parts[22],
                HDD9_Size = parts[23],
                HDD10_Size = parts[24]
            });
        }
    } while (ins != null);
    srcSR.Close();
 }

}
```

I have been googling for some ways to skip the first line, but it most of the suggestions have been to iterate through line by line and write the lines one at a time, which slows the import process (there could be hundreds of lines). Just curious if there is a simple way to tell the StreamReader where to begin reading the file.

Comment: `String.Split` is an error prone way to parse a CSV and doesnt nothing more than create a string array.  You may want to look at tools such as CSVHelper which will read the file, parse the data and store it in a nice typed collection

Comment: You've got bigger problems than “to skip the first line”; `Split(',')` does not parse CSV files. Use a CSV parser.

Comment: Also a DataGridView would be much much more well suited for the UI display - show a datasource with 1 line of code and no data type transforms

Comment: If I may, why didn't you use something already existent, like CsvHelper from nuget which, as far as I recall, is very flexible, reliable and easy to use?

Answer (score 3):

You want to read a line and throw it away. Just add an `ins = srcSR.ReadLine();` right above your `do`.